# Segue after login with facebook ios 6

Tags: facebook, ios6, segue

I'm using `Facebook SDK 3.1`, my login system is ok, after login in I want to go to other `ViewController`. I connected both with a segue and the identifier, but now I don't know how I can implement it.

Here, after this:

```
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    [self.buttonLoginLogout setTitle:@"Log out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    [self.textNoteOrLink setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@", appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken]];
}
```

On my TableViewCell example I'm using it like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"test"]) {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        RestauranteDetalhesViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.idRest =[bd.idrestauracao objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
}
```

But here I don't have a indexpath to give to the (id)sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Fabio Cardoso there are two types of Segues

1. Trigger less segue and
2. Triggered segue

In trigger less segue you just directly drag from one ViewController to another. You dont mention on which action you want the Segue to be done. To do this you need to create segue identifier like you did above. And call the below line in your code.

**[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER" sender:self];**

In second way of segue you directly Ctrl+drag from a button to another ViewController. So no need of writing any code for this. When ever you click on that button it will either do Push, Model or custom segue what ever you selected in storyboard.

When a segue if performed below method is called in the Source ViewController. Here you can write you own code to either pass value from first ViewController to another or any other stuff.

**-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender**

If there are more than one segue from your ViewController than the identifier will be of use. You can use the identifier like this

**if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"])**

Note: Segue is only one way, so if you create segue from first ViewController to another and if you want to come back (In case of model action) you have to write the delegate method for second ViewController and on clicking the button action call

```
    **FirstViewController.h**

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
{

}

- (IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender;

**FirstViewController.m**

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"])
    {
        SecondViewController *svc_obj = segue.destinationViewController;
        svc_obj.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void) buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER" sender:self];
}

- (void) secondViewControllerDidCancel: (SecondViewController *) controller
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

**SecondViewController.h**

@class SecondViewController;

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) secondViewControllerDidCancel: (SecondViewController *) controller;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{

}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)cancelButtonTapped:(id)sender;

**SecondViewController.m**

- (IBAction)cancelButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate secondViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with this simple line:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"begin" sender:self];
```